# GhostScript Image Quality issue while Printing

Tags: image, printing, ghostscript

Am using GhostScript.Net 1.2.0 version. Am converting a pdf file into list of images to print. My Printed image height and width is fine but the printed image quality is poor. Please help me how to improve the image quality while converting a pdf to image using ghostscript.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to either take this up with the Ghostscript.Net maintainer or find some way to tell us what command line/configuration you are using (ALL of it!), you will also need to supply an example file and define what you find objectionable in your current prints. 'image quality is poor' is extremely subjective, not helpful at all, there could be many, many reasons for 'poor quality', starting with your input file.

You also need to state what operating system you are using, and what your printing setup is. If you have tried anything already, then you need to say what you have done or we will waste much time suggesting dead ends.

Note that if you are using the mswinpr2 device, there may be little that can be done as that relies on the printer driver in the Windows system to do the actual printing.